# ttkbootstrap bgerror failed to handle background error

Tags: tkinter, ttkwidgets, ttkbootstrap

Python Console Window:

[image: Python Console Window]

Hoping someone can help with this error I am receive anytime i ran a program consecutively in ttkbootstrap without restarting the console. If i restart the console window it does not occur.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import pandas as pd


root = ttk.Window(title="Hello", themename="superhero")
root.geometry("800x650")

root.mainloop()
```

If i have this simple window and run it, close it, and run it again, I get the error message in the attached picture. Also, in subsequent runs my program does not seem to be incorporating ttkbootstrap widgets. Only when i restart the console does it run right. Any assistance with getting around this would be great.

Comment: What is *"console"*? Cannot reproduce the issue in Windows 11 console.

Comment: I added a image. The Python Console window. Im using Pycharm by the way

Comment: It is obviously an issue on PyCharm and nothing related to `tkinter` or `ttkbootstrap`..

Comment: Good to know. We only have access to pycharm at work. Ill try it on vs code and see if that works.